# What is the difference between "moin" and "moin moin"?

Tags: phrase, dialect, regional, salutation, northern-german

"Moin" and "moin moin" both are popular salutations in northern Germany - I'm interested in the differences between them.

Some say "moin moin" is intended as an answer to "moin", others will label anyone saying "moin moin" as a "Schnacker", i.e. a chatterbox.

So what exactly is the difference between "moin" and "moin moin"?

---

"Moin" und "moin moin" sind beides beliebte Begrüßungen in Norddeutschland - ich frage mich, wo der Unterschied liegt.

Die einen sagen, "moin moin" ist die Antwort auf "moin", für die anderen sind alle Moin-Moin-Sager "Schnacker", also Quasseltaschen.

Was genau ist nun der Unterschied zwischen "moin" und "moin moin"?

Comment: Das stimmt, wie die Flensburger-Werbungen beweisen, kann alles über eine Silbe nur von Schnackern kommen ;)

Comment: @OregonGhost Genau :-) Ich hatte auch noch kurz nach nem Link zu so einer Werbung gesucht, aber auf die Schnelle leider nix gefunden...

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9HGEY-dz00 - das ist die gute alte einsilbige ;)

Comment: Der gleiche wie zw. Bye und Bye-Bye.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Moin moin* means *Guten Morgen* (good morning), literally *Schönen Morgen* (beautiful morning), from Low German. It's similar in Dutch and I think Frisian as well.

*Moin* is short for *Moin moin* and means just *Guten* or *Schönen* and can therefore be used all day. In Northern Germany (well, Schleswig-Holstein at least) you'll encounter *Moin moin* all day as well though.

Note that *Moin* may also mean *Morgen* in Southern German dialects, not to be confused with *Moin* in Northern Germany...

By the way, *Guten* is also used informally when starting too eat, short for *Guten Appetit*. Don't use *Moin* in this context though ;)

---

*Moin moin* heißt *Guten Morgen*, wörtlich *Schönen Morgen*, aus dem Plattdeutschen. Im Niederländischen und (glaube ich) Friesischen ist es ähnlich.

*Moin* ist eine Kurzform von *Moin moin* und heißt nur *Guten* oder *Schönen*. Daher kann es den ganzen Tag verwendet werden. Im Norden (zumindest in Schleswig-Holstein) sagt man aber mitunter auch *Moin moin* zu anderen Tageszeiten.

*Moin* kann in süddeutschen Dialekten auch für *Morgen* stehen, und sollte daher nicht mit dem norddeutschen *Moin* verwechselt werden...

*Guten* wird informell auch als Kurzfrom für *Guten Appetit* beim Essen verwendet. In diesem Zusammenhang sollte man *Moin* aber nicht verwenden ;)

Comment: Eine beliebte Fehlleistung beim Essen ist es auch, "Gesundheit" statt "Guten Appetit" zu sagen. Peinlich, peinlich... :-) Bitte sagt mir, daß ich damit nicht alleine bin!

Comment: @Jan: Na, immerhin darf man laut Knigge seit 2008 wieder Gesundheit sagen, wenn jemand niest, anstatt dass jener sich entschuldigen muss... :D Aber wie, ähm, "Gesundheit" statt "Guten Appetit"? Obwohl, bei so Sachen wie der aktuellen EHEC-Geschichte passt das ja... Böser Faux-Pas wäre das aber, wenn du als militanter Vegetarier an einem Fleischessertisch das Essen mit "Gesundheit" einleiten würdest :p

Comment: @OregonGhost: es passiert ja nicht absichtlich, sondern man will den "Standardgruß" zum Essens-Anfang bringen, nur dass einem dann statt *Guten Appetit* eben der "Standardgruß" zum Niesen - *Gesundheit* - rausrutscht... Davon abgesehen: ein Leben als militanter Vegetarier mag ich mir grad nicht vorstellen ;-) Führt jetzt aber zu weit.

Comment: Moin heißt NICHT Guten Morgen, das ist ein häufiges Missverständnis. Moin heißt einfach nur Guten. Und da es zu jeder Tageszeit verwendet wird lässt es sich eher mit Guten Tag als guten Morgen übersetzen.

Comment: @Hinek: Äh, ja. Das hab ich doch geschrieben.

Comment: Im Niederländischen ist "mooi" "schön".

Comment: @Oregon: Das leitet sich übrigens vom ostfriesischen "moi" für "gut" ab. Im holländischen heißt "moi" ebenfalls "gut".

Comment: @Tomalak & @Isotopp: Ja, irgendwie so dachte ich mir das auch. Holländisch, ostfriesisch, plattdeutsch, ist doch alles recht eng verwandt :)

Comment: @OregonGhost Danke schoen fuer die Erklaerung (bei der anderen Antwort).  Ich habe bestimmt schlechte Information gekriegt...

Comment: A single "moin" is also sometimes used in South Jutland/Sønderjylland/Nordschleswig.

Answer (score 7):

Just wanted to add that I'm pretty sure there's a regional factor in this as well. I'm from the Bremen/Oldenburg area, and "Moin" is definitely the common form and "Moin Moin" is very rare.

When I hear a "Moin Moin" it's either from someone from further north (i.e. Hamburg and beyond) or from a (usually older) person who grew up speaking platt - or from someone trying to mimic either of the aforementioned for (comic) effect...

Answer (score 5):

From several vacations in northern Germany I've heard that a person entering a store or arriving at some location greets everyone already there by saying "Moin". Other people then return the greeting by responding "Moin Moin".

Comment: True, you see this all the time. It doesn't explain the actual difference between the two forms though ;)

Answer (score 5):

Ich bin in der Region aufgewachsen, in der "Westfählisches Platt" noch einen gewissen Einfluss auf die Alltagssprache hat. Recht nahe am friesischen/nordischen Plattdeutsch, aber mit einer Reihe von Eigenheiten und anderen kulturellen Einflüssen.

Ich habe "moin" und "moin moin" als *freundlichen*, *semi-informellen* Gruß gelernt. Semi-informell im Sinne dass man auch Unbekannte oder sogar Amts- und Würdenträger wie z.B. Polizisten damit grüßen kann *sofern* der Kontext noch nicht "offiziell" ist.

Der Unterschied zwischen "moin" und "moin moin" wurde mir damals so erklärt, dass das erste "moin" auf eine form von "mooii" = "schön" zurückgeht, das  zweite "moin" aber auf "morn" = "Morgen" zurückzuführen ist. "Moin moin" hieße vor dem Hintergrund also "Guten Morgen", und wird explizit nur am Morgen verwendet, während "moin" alleine "Guten/Schönen..." bedeutet mit offen gelassener Tageszeit; dementsprechend kann "moin" alleine den ganzen Tag über verwendet werden.

Etymologisch steht diese Erklärung, soweit ich das beurteilen kann, auf recht wackeligen Füßen, kulturell scheint aber die oben beschriebene *Verwendung* in meiner Heimatstadt um Umgebung (nördliches Münsterland) zuzutreffen - "Moin" höre ich dort den ganzen Tag über, "moin moin" hingegen wird fast ausschließlich morgens und vormittags verwendet.

Obligatorischer Disclaimer: Dies ist persönliche subjective Wahrnehmung, meine Datengrundlage ist nicht groß genug um als representativ zu gelten, etc. etc. Der Beitrag ist gedacht als kleine interessante Fußnote.

Answer (score 2):

Wie man anhand der bereits gegebenen Antworten sieht, wird *Moin* stets als Gruß interpretiert, *Moin Moin* hingegen scheint von Region zu Region unterschiedliche Verwendungen zu finden. [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Moin&oldid=89181171#Verwendung) sagt hierzu, dass ein *Moin Moin* nur als Gruß verwendet wird, wenn sich daraufhin ein Gespräch entwickeln soll. Das klingt für mich einleuchtend.

Aus eigener Erfahrung sei allerdings noch erwähnt, dass in einigen landwirtschaftlich geprägten Regionen oftmals nur *Moin* verwendet wird. Grüßt man dort mit *Moin Moin* wird man oft für einen Auswärtigen/Touristen gehalten.

Comment: Kann aus Erfahrung nicht bestätigen, dass Moin moin nur ein Gespräch einleitet. Dafür habe ich es zu oft als normalen Gruß gehört. Das betrifft zumindest Holstein, wo ich herkomme.

Answer (score -4):

I see it as the same difference as here in the U.S. where we say good morning vs morning.

Comment: Nope, sorry. "Moin" *does not indicate "morning"*. The greeting is perfectly acceptable at 8pm, too.